# Does Google Play allow for the caching of your entire collection on a mobile device?

Tags: google-play-music

Without having to play each individual song once, is it possible to cache the music collection stored on a Google Play account onto a device (in my case, a Nexus 5)?

Answer (score -1):

No option to do this exists. You'll need to select each song individually.

To make it easier you could arrange by album instead of song, because you likely have fewer albums than individual songs.

Comment: You don't need to select songs individually. You can mark albums and playlists for download.